# Bind List of XML to Treeview in WPF

Tags: wpf, xml-parsing, treeview

I have List of XML, I want to display it on Tree view, The Parent node will be XML file name and child will b the XML Node data and its attributes.
I m looking for generic solution so that i can load any no of xml from file system.
How i can use HierarchicalDataTemplate and XmlDataProvider

Please help me in that.

Comment: Could you give an example of how the XML looks like? Anyway, you can use LinQ to retrieve data from an XML-file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own XmlViewModel class. This class must have a property Header, Attributes and Children, and also any other things that a generic XML file should have. If you want this class need to be able to parse you XML text. Then you have to create a HierarchicalDataTemplate that represent this class in the TreeView. Some thing like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate 
      DataType="{x:Type local:XmlViewModel }" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
      >
...
```

By last you need to bind the TreeView.ItemSource to a Collection of XmlViewModels. 
maybe some thing like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding YourRoot.Children}">
...
```

Also see these two links, will be helpful to you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17025/Custom-TreeView-Layout-in-WPF

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode

Hope this help you to solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Here is another codeproject link:

[TreeView XML](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13099/Loading-and-Saving-a-TreeView-control-to-an-XML-fi)

I used this one and it got me up and going very quickly.  I ended up expanding on it significantly, but it was a good starting point.